# How to setup FFServer with FFMPEG package on window?

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, ffserver

I am running FFMPEG package in my Window PC. I want to start live streaming part with FFSERVER. I didn't find any ffserver.exe files to download. I am running with the many query:

In FFMPEG document, there are ask to configuration ffserver.conf files. and its fetch from etc/ffserver/cong. How do i find this file and their location in my computer?

I want simple basic step to run ffserver on window.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know `ffserver` is not available in the Windows builds:

> ffserver (Linux only, though with Cygwin it might work on Windows)

[Source](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide)

There are a number of open-source streaming servers available covering multiple protocols.

Comment: Can you tell me the open-source streaming server name which i can use?

Comment: @Digant Sure, what live-streaming protocol do you need?

Comment: I have CodeIgnetor Website, I have user who can create live stream event and multiple people can watch it. but it can within website. no third party application. I need code or open source so i can integrate it.

Comment: @ aergistal,  I have tired this but there is no proper step to integrate it. i mean which software is download, how to run this in local...where to setup folder/files. can you help me for ?

Comment: @Digant Forgot you're on Windows. Try [Red5](http://red5.org/) or [OBS](https://obsproject.com/).

Comment: I am fine with linux also..i can transfer my server to VPS. can you guide me? digantdave09@gmail.com